# How to create an automatic add data to CoreData Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I would like to have been created automatically months. If now is January, App should add January as first row, and then each of the first day of the month adds another month.

This should be used as a function of the viewDidLoad? After starting the program checks to see what is the month? If the month is different than added then adds another?

Thanks for help.
Regards,
Mateusz Fraczek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just compare in the `viewDidLoad` method or in `AppDelegate` the actual year and month with the newest month in your CoreData-Database. Be careful to also save the year, because otherwise the method won't work after the first year.

You could also use `NSUserDefaults` to store the actual month, but as you will use CoreData to save the date into the DB anyway, you can use CoreData to check right away.

Comment: Be careful, `viewDidLoad` won't get called if the app resumes from the background, so I would go with one of the application lifecycle methods in the app delegate.